# Show maintenance message on all JupyterHub notebooks

Tags: jupyterhub

I manage a JupyterHub instance for the data-scientists in our company. Is there a way to show a maintenance message on all the notebooks of the users to inform them of upcoming downtime?

Comment: As long as I know, there is no way. But you can always temporally modify the templates: [as in the documents](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/templates.html#custom-templates). Add some HTML then remove when done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may looking for [page announcement](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/templates.html#page-announcements) feature. As per docs, there seems two available options to add announcements to be displayed on a page:

1. Extend the page templates
2. Use configuration variables (requires restart).

> If you set the configuration variable
>
> JupyterHub.template_vars = {'announcement': 'some_text}, the given some_text will be placed on
>   the top of all pages. The more specific variables **announcement_login**,
>   **announcement_spawn**, **announcement_home**, and **announcement_logout** are
>   more specific and only show on their respective pages (overriding the
>   global announcement variable). Note that changing these variables
>   require a restart, unlike direct template extension.

Moreover there is an [example of announcement service](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/tree/master/examples/service-announcement) available in official repository on building the custom service.

Hope it helps.